# how to pull array of results from http Post result of ModelMultipleChoiceField in django view

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-post

I print the request POST after submitting a form with a ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            print 'form ' + str(request.POST)
            for i in request.POST['groups_field']:
                print i
```

This first print prints this:

form

The second print prints this:

```
4
```

Why does this only pull the last selected value?

The form field looks like this:

```
groups_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.none(), 
                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

How can I pull out the list of group fields selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `request.POST.getlist('groups_field')`